# idh_hist query is very slow while searching with date

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to write a query to search thru MFG/PRO invoice table 'idh_hist' for specific date range. It is running very slow when added the date condition. But when I put off the date condition, it is very fast. Can you please suggest ways to write a query on idh_hist that runs reasonably faster with conditions.

Following is my query:

```
for each idh_hist no-lock where idh_domain = "d0002"
                            and idh_due_date = TODAY:

    /* display code here... */

end.
```

Thanks in advance!

Database Index:

```
Flags Index Name              Cnt   Field Name
----- ---------------------  ----   ---------------------
      idh_fsm_type             4    + idh_domain
                                    + idh_fsm_type
                                    + idh_nbr
                                    + idh_line

pu    idh_invln                4    + idh_domain
                                    + idh_inv_nbr
                                    + idh_nbr
                                    + idh_line

      idh_part                 4    + idh_domain
                                    + idh_part
                                    + idh_inv_nbr
                                    + idh_line

u     oid_idh_hist             1    + oid_idh_hist
```

Comment: Can you share the index definitions on the idh_hist table with us?

Comment: Hi @MikeFechner, I have added the index herewith. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not appear to have an index that uses idh_due_date.  You will need to add such an index.

The 4gl uses rules to select indexes based on the WHERE clause.  The most important rule is that leading components of the index which have equality matches will be used.

The query you have shown only has one such match on idh_domain.  So then tie breaker rules are applied.  This will result in the idh_invln index being chosen.

As it is, to satisfy your query all records that match the "idh_domain" field need to be searched.  (If you only have one domain that means that you are doing a table scan.)

You probably want to add an index on idh_domain and idh_due_date.  That would be a perfect match for your query.

Comment: A lot of thanks @Tom. BTW, can I add custom index into QAD standard tables?

Comment: There is no technical barrier to doing so.  Only FUD would prevent you.